# change the content of div

Tags: javascript

I want to change div content,

this is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText(){
    document.getElementById('df').value = 'changed';
}
</script>
<div id="df"></div>
<input type='button' onclick='changeText()' value='Change'/>
```

Nothing happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `innerHTML`, not `value`

```
function changeText(){
    document.getElementById('df').innerHTML = 'changed';
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YTzdN/)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('df').innerHTML = 'changed';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
function changeText(){
    document.getElementById('df').innerHTML = 'changed';
}
```

Also -this is the actual html, not just text.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$('#df').append("changed");
```

Comment: No mention of jquery being included here.  Can't assume he can do this.

Comment: Not to mention this appends content, does not replace existing content with changed value.